# jq filter and select multiple conditions and columns

Tags: jq, hadoop-yarn

I want to parse Hadoop Yarn job history files into csv/sql format to query them easily.

I extracted the AVRO schema from .jhist files, converted avro data files to stream-of-jsons using avro-tools-*.jar, combined the stream into a single json using jq, and now I need to extract certain fields from certain individual jsons

```
[
  {
    "type": "AM_STARTED",
    "event": {
      "AMStarted": {
        "startTime": 1636039435822,
        "nodeManagerPort": 8041
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "TASK_STARTED",
    "event": {
      "TaskStarted": {
        "taskid": "task_1351",
        "jobStatus": "Started"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "JOB_INITED",
    "event": {
      "JobInited": {
        "launchTime": 1636039438569,
        "totalMaps": 356,
        "totalReduces": 100
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "JOB_FINISHED",
    "event": {
      "JobFinished": {
        "jobid": "job_1636039105678_0061",
        "finishTime": 1636043211181,
        "totalCounters": {
          "name": "TOTAL_COUNTERS",
          "groups": [
            {
              "name": "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter",
              "displayName": "File System Counters",
              "counts": [
                {
                  "name": "FILE_BYTES_READ",
                  "displayName": "FILE: Number of bytes read",
                  "value": 1156766568459
                },
                {
                  "name": "FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN",
                  "displayName": "FILE: Number of bytes written",
                  "value": 1720873364662
                },
                {
                  "name": "RANDOM_BYTES",
                  "displayName": "RANDOM: Bytes",
                  "value": 1720873311162
                }
                ]
            }
            ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

From type AM_STARTED 'json/index/row', I want *event.AMStarted.startTime*
Ignore TASK_STARTED - I do not want anything that has 'TASK' in type
From JOB_INITED, I want all fields
From JOB_FINISHED, I want finishTime, and values of FILE_BYTES_READ & FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN

I want all these to be comma-separated (and maybe "quoted"), so I can load them into a csv and then into a sql table.

Expected Output :

> 1636039435822, 1636039438569, 356, 100, 1636043211181, 1156766568459, 1720873364662

What's the syntax for [this](https://jqplay.org/s/T6HtocRjGW)?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following :

```
jq -r 'map(.event | (.AMStarted.startTime // .JobQueueChange.jobQueueName // .JobInited[])) | @csv'
```

`map` applies a mapping to every element of your input array ; we access their event, then try to access either `.AMStarted.startTime`, `.JobQueueChange.jobQueueName` or `.JobInited` which we split into its components. The `@csv` filter outputs the resulting array in your expected format.

Note that this disregards the filter you wanted on the object's `.type`, I assume this is ok given that the object held by `.event` is just as specific.

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/OPgp2HWpMe).

Comment: thx. turns out I DO need a filter on .type because there are hundreds of TASK_STARTED types that I need to ignore. If not, I end up with several ,,,,,,,, of ignored events in my csv. Is there an elegant way to filter inside map, or the below answer of 'select'ing is the way to go ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought objects that didn't match one of the three criteria wouldn't appear in the output. I can't deal with it immediately but I'll try to fix my answer soon, in the meantime could your edit your sample input to add a sample of object that should be ignored?

Comment: also got an error (cannot iterate over nulls, cos of the JobInited[]). See updated [here](https://jqplay.org/s/hVAXsSNVU0)

Comment: @d-_-b is [this](https://jqplay.org/s/Q3Eh-Wxyn9) what you're looking for?

Comment: can we specify .type not contains 'TASK' ? Also, I need some nested elements which are also filtered. Not sure if I have to specify the entire path or there's a way to sub-group & select elements having same path. Updated question

Comment: The `select` in my command filters on the `.type`s you want, I just messed up and specified the "TASK_STARTED" type instead of the "JOB_INITED" one. For the nested path traversal you can add it as another part of the alternation, start the traversal from the `.event` and address your desired path like you would in another context

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer to the original question:

> From type AM_STARTED 'json/index/row', I want event.AMStarted.startTime
> From type JOB_QUEUE_CHANGED, I want event.JobQueueChange.jobQueueName
> From type JOB_INITED, I want event.JobInited.{launchTime, totalMaps, totalReduces}

```sh
jq --raw-output '
  map(
    select(.type == "AM_STARTED").event.AMStarted.startTime,
    select(.type == "JOB_QUEUE_CHANGED").event.JobQueueChange.jobQueueName,
    select(.type == "JOB_INITED").event.JobInited["launchTime", "totalMaps", "totalReduces"]
  )
| @csv'
```

Try it [here](https://jqplay.org/s/IdWJmYk4fZ).

---

This is the answer to the updated question:

> From type AM_STARTED 'json/index/row', I want event.AMStarted.startTime
> Ignore TASK_STARTED - I do not want anything that has 'TASK' in type
> From JOB_INITED, I want all fields
> From JOB_FINISHED, I want finishTime, and values of FILE_BYTES_READ & FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN

```sh
jq --raw-output '
  map(
    select(.type == "AM_STARTED").event.AMStarted.startTime,
    select(.type == "JOB_INITED").event.JobInited[],
    (
      select(.type == "JOB_FINISHED").event.JobFinished
      | .finishTime,
      (
        .totalCounters.groups[].counts[] | (
          select(.name == "FILE_BYTES_READ").value,
          select(.name == "FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN").value
        )
      )
    )
  )
  | @csv
'
```

Try it [here](https://jqplay.org/s/4U5H-Ml47i).

Comment: how can i select multiple fields which are in different nesting levels ? see updated question above (BYTES_READ & WRITTEN)

Comment: I updated my answer.